# Get/Connect to Local SharePoint SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server

How does one find the name of, or connect to the SQL instance, that SharePoint uses when you perform a basic/local install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the registry here:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0\Secure\ConfigDb
```